# Need advice with logic in the loop

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

I have three elements of the doubly-linked list, and I have two operations: `foo()` and `bar()`.

Based on some boolean flag I have to perform `foo()` operation (if `true`) on the FIRST of the two elements, and `bar()` operation (if `false`) on the remaining single element.

So, this is the clean code, but wrong because it performs foo() on both elements:

```
while(head->next != NULL)
{
   if(head->flag == true)
   { 
      foo();
   }
   if(head->flag == false)
   {
      bar();
   }
   head = head->next;
}
```

List elements may come in random order, so it could be A, C, B or B, A, C (while let's say A and B in both cases require `foo()` operation).

My problem is that if A and B come first, I'll call foo() function on both of them (and I can't as stated above).

Actually, as I analyzite it again, I see that in every case I'll get this function called twice.

The solution I've came up with is:

```
int flag = 0;
while(head->next != NULL)
{
   if(head->flag == true && flag == 0)
   { 
      foo();
      flag = 1;
   }
   if(head->flag == false)
   {
      bar();
   }
   head = head->next;
}
```

But the code suddenly becomes ugly.

Is there a way to solve this without using flags, and keeping code clean?

Comment: The code doesn't look ugly to me. Maybe in your implementation of your linked list, you could add a `bool` that is set to `true` if it is the first element of the list and `false` otherwise.

Comment: my own implementation

Comment: The function is quite larger actually, flags make it less readable.

Comment: Yes, head variable. In this code head should be "temp" to keep an order, but I wanted this to be more readable.

Comment: Well, I thought there is some way without flags, neither in the loop nor inside the structure. But if there's not I'm ok to do this with flags, thanks.

Comment: You would have to change your implementation of the linked list if you want to do it another way. The posted answer seems incorrect.

Comment: Why not just jump over the next element after a call to `foo` keep a flag for that jump inside the loop so it is initialized each iteration, you'll have `head = head->next` two times in you loop, check if not null after incrementing `head`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void NullFunc( void ) {}
void (*operation)(void) = foo;

while( head->next != NULL )
{
    if( head->flag == true )
    {
         operation();
         operation = NullFunc;
    }
    else
    {
        bar();
    }

    head = head->next;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this call `bar()` on the second element that is `true`. OP said that he wants to call `bar()` only when `flag` is `false`.

Comment: You are correct... I missed that he only wanted to call `bar()` on a `false` flag. The above correction should fix that.